# How to override the pip command to Python3.x instead of Python2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am using OSX and I have pip installed for both Python3.5 and Python2.7. I know I can run the command `pip2` to use Python2 and when I use the command `pip3` Python3.x will be used. 
The problem is that the default of `pip` is set to Python2.7 and I want it to be Python3.x.

How can I change that?

edit:
No, I am not running a virtual environment yet. If it was a virtual environment I could just run Python3.x and forget all about Python2.7, unfortunately since OSX requires Python2.7 for it's use I can't do that. Hence why I'm asking this.

Thanks for the answer. I however don't want to change what running `python` does. Instead I would like to change the path that running `pip` takes. At the moment `pip -V` shows me `pip 8.1.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`, but I am looking for `pip 8.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)` I am sure there has to be a way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running in a virtualenv? (and if not, you should probably do that first)

Comment: I plan on running a virtualen in the near future, but would like to get this working first.

Comment: The virtualenv will override your `PATH` so the right python is invoked. You should start with the virtualenv, it is designed exactly for that purpose.

Comment: if you didn't want to use virtual environment you could just re-organize your PATH..

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen How would I do that? SO far the only thing I can think of doing is assigning an `alias pip='pip3'`, but I think there has to be a better way.

Comment: see http://daniel.hepper.net/blog/2011/02/change-order-of-path-entries-on-mac-os-x/, seems the best way according to that is to edit `/etc/paths`

Answer (score 82):

Run this:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force pip
```

or even more explicit:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

This will install pip for Python 3 and make Python 3 version of pip default.

Validate with:

```
pip -V
```

Comment: To validate, use `python3 -m pip -V`

Comment: does not work. Still pip is using Python 2.7 for me, after doing the above steps

Comment: ```pip3 install --upgrade --force pip``` works, thank you.

Answer (score 49):

I always just run it via Python itself, this way:

```
python3 -m pip install some_module
```

or

```
python2 -m pip install some_module
```

The `-m` calls the `__main__.py` module of a specified package. Pip supports this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can do that, but that's not what I was looking for. I want `pip` to lead to Python3.x by default.

Answer (score 10):

Can't you `alias pip='pip3'` in your `~/.bash_profile`?

In Terminal, run `nano ~/.bash_profile`, then add a line to the end that reads `alias pip='pip3'`. This is safe; it won't affect system processes, only your terminal.

Comment: …but any bash script you run that has a `pip` in it will still run `/usr/bin/pip`, as aliases are not expanded in subscripts. So be very cautious with this.

Comment: Right. But if OP is looking for convenience when installing packages normally, this is the way to go. For my terminal, I have `python=ipython3`, `python2=ipython`, `vanilla-python=python3` and `vanilla-python2=python`, and `pip=pip3`, and it makes working in Python 3 much faster.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Thanks luke, I didn't want to resort to that, but It'll have to do for now until I figure how to change the actual path. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

For your projects, you should be using a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

You can choose which python will be that of the virtualenv at creation time, by specifying it on the command line:

```
virtualenv -p python3 env
# then
. env/bin/activate
python              # ← will run python3
```

That python interpreter will be the one used when you run `python` or `pip` while the virtualenv is active.

Under the hood, activating the virtualenv will:

- modify your `PATH` environment setting so binaries in `env/bin`
  override those from your system.
- modify your `PYTHONHOME`
  environment setting so python modules are loaded from `env/lib`.

So `python`, `pip` and any other package you install with `pip` will be run from the virtualenv, with the python version you chose and the package versions you installed in the virtualenv.

Other than this, running `python` without using virtualenv will just run the default python of the system, which you cannot usually change as it would break a lot of system scripts.

Comment: I've never used `virtualenv` besides heavy python-ing, this is one of the first compelling cases I've seen for my Python usage (though I haven't really gone looking for any)

Comment: It is a good idea for other reasons as well. For instance, it guarantees that upgrading your system will not break your project (though you might have to update the virtualenv).

Comment: ah, neat. I'll look into it

Comment: And how to make pip a pip3 command by default in a virtual environment of python2.x? Since it does not help changing the executing command when you have sub-commands in the files calling the old pip again - and you need to install it in that virtual venv.

Answer (score 5):

It works for me:

**As super-user**

Uninstall pip

```
sudo pip uninstall pip
```

Install pip

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

Check install path

```
sudo pip -V
```

**As local-user**

Uninstall pip

```
pip uninstall pip
```

Install pip

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

Check install path

```
pip -V
```

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Answer (score 1):

Although [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) does not specifically mention `pip`, it does discuss a number of other Python-related commands (including `python` itself).  The short version is that, for reasons of backwards compatibility, the unversioned commands should refer to Python 2.x for the immediate future on most reasonable systems.

Generally, these aliases are implemented as symbolic links, and you can just flip the symlink to point at the version you want (e.g. with `ln -f -s $(which pip3) $(which pip)` as root).  But it may not be a good idea if you have any software that expects to interact with Python 2 (which may be more than you think since a lot of software interacts with Python).

The saner option is to set up a [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) with Python 3.  Then, *within the Virtualenv*, all Python-related commands will refer to 3.x instead of 2.x.  This will not break the system, unlike the previous paragraph which could well break things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kevin, do you think that changing `pip` will break the compatibility though? I want to leave the `python` default to Python2.7 I just want to change the version that `pip` points to, it's all.

Comment: @lokil> you should not install packages with `pip` outside of a virtualenv anyway, it will break your python installation.

Comment: @spectras I will take your advice and do virtualen, but my question still stands. If I wanted to change the path that `pip` points to... How would I do it?

Comment: As Kevin says in this very answer, you would delete `/usr/bin/pip` and recreate it as a link to the one you want, using the command he put in his answer. And you'd probably be left with a non-working python after using it for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specified in the comments you want syntax like `pip install [package]` to work, here is a solution:

1. Install `setuptools` for `Python3`: `apt-get install python3-setuptools`
2. Now `pip` for `Python3` could be installed by: `python3 -m easy_install pip`
3. Now you can use `pip` with the specific version of Python to
   install package for Python 3 by: `pip-3.2 install [package]`

Answer (score -1):

Why not just repoint the link /bin/python to python3?  It seems like the easiest solution.  Especially if you want it for all users of your system.

Comment: Please consider providing commands to do so to make it a complete answer.