# cant use pip3, gives me errors

Tags: linux

hey i have 2 versions of python on my computer(2.7 and 3.5), im trying to use pip3, but it shows me this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 637, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==18.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I know pip3 should work with python3 but here it shows in the error python2.7 so that's probably the error but how do i fix that to point my python 3.5.2.

thank you very much!

Comment: try `pip install pip --upgrade`

Comment: Or have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38938246/338019

Comment: it gives me an exception  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

Give these a go

```
python3 -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```