# How to update scrapy from 1.8.0. to newest (2.1.0) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: scrapy, ubuntu-18.04

I installed scrapy recently by using the pip command (`pip install scrapy`). Now I discovered that the installed version is 1.8.0. How to get it updated to the most recent 2.1.0? Uninstalling and reinstall did not work.

**UPDATE, PARTLY SOLVED:** 
I updated ip through `python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`. That did not change the outcome of the `pip install -U scrapy`. But forcing pip to be run by python3 did. So after `python3 -m pip install -U scrapy` my scrapy version is now `2.1.0`. Looks like some issues with the two python versions on my machines and some settings? Anybody can shine a light on this?

Comment: Did you try `pip install -U Scrapy`?

Comment: Now I did, didn't help unfortunately

Comment: I say this in the output of above statement: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I tried (after some googling) `pip install --upgrade pip`. It installed pip-20.1.1. Then I tried `pip install -U scrapy` again and now I got a Depracated warning about Pytho 2.7. And that I shoudl use `-m pi` instead. So then I tried `python -m pip install -U Scrapy` which gave a lot of lines with `Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade....`.  

Still stuck with scrapy 1.8.0 unfortunately.

Comment: You can use `pip2 install ...` and `pip3 install ...` to make sure the right Python version is used. The commands you mentioned to set pip=pip3 as default agree with the following answer except that it should be `python3 -m pip install --update ..` https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494352/5350621