# Can't import Image from PIL because of this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

When I import Image from PIL I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 94, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

The way it says to install pillow errors out for me

```
pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

It says that it doesn't have the .whl so it defaults to the old setup.py then errors and doesn't install.

only

```
sudo apt install python3-pil
```

seems to install pillow correctly

this is for python3.8.x

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip3` instead of `pip`. `pip` sometimes defaults to Python 2.x. See the following question to change this behavior: [How to override the pip command to Python3.x instead of Python2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938205/how-to-override-the-pip-command-to-python3-x-instead-of-python2-7/38938246)

```
pip3 install --upgrade Pillow
```