# vs code terminal says python 2.7, but I have 3.8 selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

Okay, so my vs code file is importing yfinance and when I do all of the pip commands I get a caution since its using the python 2.7 while I have the 3.8 selected in the bottom left.  Been struggling on this error for many hours and cannot quite figure it out.   [Screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4evQ.png)

Comment: Selecting interpreter in VSCode doesn't affect the terminal, only changing which interpreter is used when executing currently opened file/project in VSCode itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `python3` command for Python 3x commands. Even for pip, it needs pip3, pip for Python 3.

Check this answer [How to override the pip command to Python3.x instead of Python2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938205/how-to-override-the-pip-command-to-python3-x-instead-of-python2-7)