# unable to import opencv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pip

I am trying to import opencv for webcam capturing and Keras to use AI, however, it returns an error showing that the module isn't found.

I used both `pip install opencv-python` and `python -m pip install opencv-python` but I still cannot import it.

(I'm using python 3.9.6)

Comment: you are probably calling a different `pip` try `pip3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have python 2.x installed on your machine and is set as default for your `pip`. You could check this by running `pip --version` on your terminal and it should show you which version of python it is using. If it shows python 2.x, then you could use `pip3` or `python3` instead to install your package as you mentioned that you are using python 3.9.6 for your project environment.

For future use, you could set python 3 as your default for `pip`. You could follow the steps given here: [How to override the pip command to Python3.x instead of Python2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38938205/16170683)

Cheers!

Comment: did you mean python 3.x?

Comment: No, you might have python 2.x installed on your machine, that is why when youre using the pip method, you are calling python 2.x instead of python 3.x. Hence, why you should use pip3 install instead because you also mentioned that you are using python 3.9.6 for your project

Comment: trying checking the module list though using pip freeze or pip3 freeze

Comment: I tried the ```python3 -m pip install opencv-python``` it works now

Comment: Great, do set this as the accepted answer if you are satisfied with my answer. Thanks Albert happy coding!