# Python script module not found on rerun of script

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, python-venv, adafruit-circuitpython

I am running a python script on RaspberryPi 4, and today when I ran the script again, it showed me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adafruit_ssd1306'` although I ran this same script yesterday about 10 times, it ran perfectly without any errors. I did not change anything in the script, not even its location. I tried force reinstalling the library,
running the script from another location, rebooting the pi, running it as `sudo` but none of them worked either.
By using `pip3 freeze` it shows that the package is installed and trying to install the package again says that the requirement is already satisfied.

Python version: 3.7

Main.py

```py
import time
import board
import digitalio
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import adafruit_ssd1306
import requests

WIDTH = 128
HEIGHT = 64  # Change to 64 if needed
BORDER = 5

BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
API_KEY = "API Key"
sign = '°'

# Use for I2C.
i2c = board.I2C()
oled = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(WIDTH, HEIGHT, i2c, addr=0x3C)

dir_pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D23)
step_pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D24)
call_b = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D18)

dir_pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
step_pin.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
call_b.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
dir_pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP
step_pin.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP

prev_value = True

cities = ['Delhi','Tokyo','London','San Francisco',
        'kanpur','Mumbai','portugal','Toronto','Sydney','Paris','New York','Dubai',
        'Moscow','Rome','Madrid','Riyadh','Bangkok','Cairo','Istanbul','Kolkata',
        'Beijing','Seoul','Shanghai','Osaka','Hong Kong','Bangalore','Kathmandu',
        'Chennai','Kathmandu','Manila','Jakarta','Tehran','Baghdad','Riyadh','Abu Dhabi',
        'Dubai','Kuala Lumpur','Chennai','Kathmandu','Manila','Jakarta','Tehran','Baghdad']

font_size = 12
font = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/Poppins-Regular.ttf', font_size)
font_big = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/Poppins-Regular.ttf', font_size+4)
font_xl = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/Poppins-Regular.ttf', font_size+7)

max_cities = len(cities) - 1
value = 0



def get_temp(city):
        url = BASE_URL + "q=" + city + "&appid=" + API_KEY
        r = requests.get(url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
                data = r.json()
                temp = data['main']['temp']
                humidity = data['main']['humidity']
        temp = int(temp)
        humidity = int(humidity)
        temp = temp - 273
        #humidity = humidity+"%"

        temp = str(temp)+sign+'c'
        # h = "Humidity: "+str(humidity)
        return temp

def create_image(temp,city):
        image = Image.new("1", (oled.width, oled.height))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        (fw,fh) = font.getsize(city)
        (w,h) = font_xl.getsize(temp)
        draw.text((128//2 - fw//2,12),city,fill=255,font=font) # city name
        draw.text((128//2 - w//2,30),temp,fill=255,font=font_xl) # temp
        return image

def text_image(city):
        image_ = Image.new("1", (oled.width, oled.height))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_)
        (font_width, font_height) = font_big.getsize(city)
        draw.text((128//2 - font_width//2, 64//2 - font_height//2),city, font=font_big, fill=255)
        oled.fill(0)
        oled.image(image_)
        oled.show()

g = "Temprature\n     Meter"
intro = Image.new("1", (oled.width, oled.height))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(intro)
# Draw text
(font_width, font_height) = font.getsize(g)
d.text((20, 6),
        g, font=font_big, fill=255)

oled.fill(0)
oled.image(intro)
oled.show()
timer = 0

while True:
        if prev_value != step_pin.value:
                if step_pin.value == False:
                        if dir_pin.value == False:

                                print("left")  # left
                                value = value + 1
                                if value > max_cities:
                                        value = 1
                                print(value)
                                selected_city = cities[value]
                                print(selected_city)
                                text_image(selected_city)

                        else:
                                print("right")  # right
                                if value == 0:
                                        value = max_cities
                                else:
                                        value = value - 1
                                print(value)
                                selected_city = cities[value]
                                print(selected_city)
                                text_image(selected_city)
                                prev_value = step_pin.value

        while call_b.value == False:
                timer = timer+1

        if timer > 70000 and timer < 150000:

                oled.fill(0)
                oled.show()
                timer = 0
                print("blank")
                time.sleep(2)
                print("active")

        elif timer < 15000 and timer > 500:

                t = get_temp(selected_city)
                print(t)
                 # display the data to the OLED
                image = create_image(t,selected_city)
                oled.fill(0) #clear display
                oled.show()
                oled.image(image)
                oled.show()
                timer = 0
                time.sleep(1)
        else:
            timer = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- make sure you typed the name of module correctly

2- make sure you use the correct python version

python3:

```
python3 script.py
```

3- also make sure it installed with the correct pip installer you may used pip for python2 by mistake

```
python3 -m pip install some_module
```

4- better way to make a virtual environment

```
virtualenv -p python3 env
# then
. env/bin/activate
python              # ← will run python3
```

you may read

[this answer on stack overflow about venv and pip versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38938280/8244253)

and [official documentation for venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

you may search for virtual environment on raspberry pi if there is any different setups may be needed but as I remember it is most likely like Ubuntu

Comment: i am running python3 and i am using the correct pip installer which u said, but the problem still persists

Comment: use `pip3 freeze`  does it show the package within the list ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703670/8244253 there is an example for this command

Comment: yes, using `pip freeze` shows the package within the list

Comment: also you wrote the module name wrong in the code in question

Comment: check this example

Comment: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306/blob/master/examples/animate.py

Comment: it should be Adafruit_SSD1306 not adafruit_ssd1306

Comment: `import Adafruit_SSD1306`  is the correct not `import adafruit_ssd1306`

Comment: `oled = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(WIDTH, HEIGHT, i2c, addr=0x3C)` also should be `oled = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_64(rst=RST)' you seem not checked examples or looked on the source code

Comment: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306/blob/master/examples/animate.py

Comment: you are right but i am using this library:https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_SSD1306 and according to it I have to import it like this `import adafruit_ssd1306` and the code worked like this but now its not

Comment: if you mean this one https://pypi.org/project/adafruit-circuitpython-ssd1306/

Comment: did you made all the steps ?

Comment: you may forgot that you made a virtual environment like  dimz pointed out https://stackoverflow.com/a/70903053/8244253

Comment: I see also the steps for virtual environment inside the link you submitted ....you may copied the lines and pasted them without further searching

Comment: see if you made a virtual environment and try to activate it

Comment: Hey, It worked on doing everything again and I will mark your answer the correct

Answer (score 1):

it is sometimes happen when I forgot to activate the virtualenv, even I can install new libraries using pip or pip3 without virtualenv. But python main.py won't run. Then I realized that I haven't turn on the virtual environment.

Comment: this is not the thing, I don't use a virtual env, I just use the default python interpreter.